# Difficulty with mongoDB connection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I am currently working on a twitter-like app using the MEAN stack and i am stuck with regards to connecting my database in my javascript file. Right now I am using this method:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var mc = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.memoryStorage();
var upload = multer({ storage: storage});

var db, postsCollection;

router.get('/', function(req,res) {
  res.render('login');
});

router.get('/register', function(req,res) {
  res.render('register');
});


mc.connect('mongodb://localhost/post-demo', function(err, returnedDB) {
  if(err) {
    throw err;
  }
    db = returnedDB;
    postsCollection = db.collection('posts');
});
module.exports = router;
```

the `mc.connect` fragment works on other programs I have worked on and I have no idea why this is not working now. On the other programs they add an empty database, but it just doesn't seem to work on this one.. Can someone please help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try again specifying the port number in the url. like `mongodb://localhost:27017/post-demo`?

Comment: How do you know it isn't working, do you have any error log ?

Comment: Why don't use [tag:mongoose]?

Comment: Hi sorry I have no idea how to use Mongoose, but I guess I will start using it.

Also, I know it is not working because when I use the mongo shell and type 'show dbs' it shows no databases at all with the name post-demo.. But for the other programs I built it makes a database with a name (even if it is empty)

Comment: @BertrandMartel I am using mongoose with the command :

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/post-demo');

It is still not working..